# Bootstrap 5: How do I make div side by side

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I would like to put these two images side by side
Here is my code:-
code

```
<div class="container-md">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p> Image Video Live Streaming </p>
            <img src="" class="p-1 bg-dark" alt="" id="video" width="400" height="500" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p> Depth Video Live Streaming </p>
            <img src="" class="p-1 bg-dark" alt="" id="video" width="400" height="500" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Kewei Ong. Do you want to do this strictly with Bootstrap or can you use some css like: .row{ display:flex; } ?

Comment: @Chris, what if I wanna keep some space between these two images?

Comment: They are already side-by-side on `md` and wider (https://codeply.com/p/kjdQoNJSQu). Please clarify the question and explain exactly what is expected.

Comment: @Zim, Hi Zim, no it wasn't. I tried with and without md, that's why i posted a question here. But it was solved by Alex Greenwood that i have to add .row {display:flex} in css.

Answer (score 2):

you code work perfectly with bootstrap 5. Added your code with dummy images in [codepen](https://codepen.io/raviafre/pen/MWpRKZg).

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p> Image Video Live Streaming </p>
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/100582/pexels-photo-100582.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-philipp-m-100582.jpg&fm=jpg" class="p-1 bg-dark" alt="" id="video" width="400" height="500" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p> Depth Video Live Streaming </p>
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/38136/pexels-photo-38136.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-veeterzy-38136.jpg&fm=jpg" class="p-1 bg-dark" alt="" id="video" width="400" height="500" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
}
```

this is *one* way to do it using CSS.

**Update**:

There is now space around the two images.

Check out this [URL](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to understand more about CSS Flexbox, and all the awesome things you can do !

Comment: i don't think it should be `inline-flex`, according to me jut `flex` will do.

Comment: what if I wanna keep some space between these two images?

Comment: I am going to update my answer. One moment.